# How to do configure,make and make install in docker build

Tags: docker, makefile, configure

**Problem Statement**

I am building a docker of my computational bioinformatics pipeline which contains many tools that will be called at different steps of pipelines. In this process, I am trying to add one tool [The ViennaRNA Package](https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/#download) which will be downloaded and compliled using source code. I have tried many ways to compile it in docker build (as shown below) but none of them is working.

**Failed attempts**

Code-1 :

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook

USER root

MAINTAINER Vivek Ruhela <vivekr@iiitd.ac.in>

# Copy the application folder inside the container
ADD . /test1

# Set the default directory where CMD will execute
WORKDIR /test1

# Set environment variable
ENV HOME /test1 

# Install RNAFold
RUN wget https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/download/sourcecode/2_4_x/ViennaRNA-2.4.14.tar.gz -P ~/Tools
RUN tar xvzf ~/Tools/ViennaRNA-2.4.14.tar.gz -C ~/Tools  
WORKDIR "~/Tools/ViennaRNA-2.4.14/"
RUN ./configure
RUN make && make check && make install
```

Error : configure file not found

Code-2 :

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook

USER root

MAINTAINER Vivek Ruhela <vivekr@iiitd.ac.in>

# Copy the application folder inside the container
ADD . /test1

# Set the default directory where CMD will execute
WORKDIR /test1

# Set environment variable
ENV HOME /test1 

# Install RNAFold
RUN wget https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/download/sourcecode/2_4_x/ViennaRNA-2.4.14.tar.gz -P ~/Tools
RUN tar xvzf ~/Tools/ViennaRNA-2.4.14.tar.gz -C ~/Tools  
RUN bash ~/Tools/ViennaRNA-2.4.14/configure
WORKDIR "~/Tools/ViennaRNA-2.4.14/"
RUN make && make check && make install
```

Error : make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

I also tried another way to tell the file location explicitly e.g.

```
RUN make -C ~/Tools/ViennaRNA-2.4.14/
```

Sill this approach is not working.

**Expected Procedure**

I have installed this tool in my system many times using the standard procedure as mentioned in tool documentation as

```
./configure
make
make check
make install
```

Similarly for docker, the following code should work

```
WORKDIR ~/Tools/ViennaRNA-2.4.14/
RUN ./configure && make && make check && make install
```

But this code is not working because I don't see any effect of workdir. I have checked that configure is creating makefile properly in my system. So it should create the make file in docker also. 
Any suggestions on why this code is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are extract all the files in `Tools` folder which is in `home` ,try this:

```
WORKDIR $HOME/Tools/ViennaRNA-2.4.14
RUN ./configure
RUN make && make check && make install
```

the problem is `WORKDIR ~/Tools/ViennaRNA-2.4.14/` is translated to exactly `~/Tools/ViennaRNA-2.4.14/` which is created a folder named `~` , you may also use `$HOME` instead

Comment: Very small and silly mistake I was doing. It worked. Thanks. I should have asked before wasting one and half hour on that problem. Thanks again. Now I'll mark this as correct answer.